# Deep linking single page application with dotNet core

Tags: asp.net-core, angular2-routing

I am using a dotNet core project to host an Angular2 application.  I am having problems with the deep linking URLs.

For example, when I initially browse to http://localhost:54675/app/dashboard I get a 404 error because there is nothing to serve at app/dashboard.  I want to actually load index.html (the angular app) and then have routing take me to app/dashboard.

I use the code below to redirect to index.html if I get a 404 and the URL has no extension.

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                await next();

                if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 && !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value))
                {
                    context.Request.Path = "/index.html"; 
                    await next();
                }
            });
```

This will not work when I have a routing with parameters that include JSON such as:
http://localhost:54675/app/repairReturnListing;filter=%7B%22Status%22:[%22AWP%22]%7D

My if statement ignores requests with an extension and Path.HasExtension throws and ArgumentException on this path.  The path resolves to this on the server side:

> "/app/repairReturnListing;filter={\"Status\":[\"AWP\"]}"

I removed the 'HasExtension' condition and then I get a lot of console errors looking for map files that I don't host.  Like this:

> Failed to parse SourceMap:
>   http://localhost:54675/lib/js/rxjs/operator/timeout.js.map

I don't get these errors in the network tab.  I think this is something used for debugging.

My angular2 app uses HTML5 routing.  I use static files to serve the angular2 application.  I have one webApi controller that returns some configuration data (the rest of the data is returned by another webApi project).

Waiting on a 404 and redirecting seems like a work-around and it's not even working.
Any suggestions on the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Check out ng2-kestrel-appserver http://tattoocoder.com/kestrel-as-a-static-server-for-angular/

Does exactly what you're looking for. It was created for RC2 but should work for the current release with few or no changes.